# Multi-level module Maven release configuration

Tags: java, maven, release

I have a java-maven project structure like this:

```
parent-project
    |-pom.xml
    |-super-child-module-1
         |-pom.xml
         |-child-1-of-super-child-module-1
                 |-pom.xml
         |-child-2-of-super-child-module-1
                 |-pom.xml
    |-super-child-module-2
         |-pom.xml
         |-child-1-of-super-child-module-2
                 |-pom.xml
         |-child-2-of-super-child-module-2
                 |-pom.xml
```

How to write a maven release configuration for the above structure?

Comment: What do you mean by a "Maven release configuration"?

Comment: I mean 'maven release plugin' for this structure

Comment: Usually, you just call the plugin and that is it.